# Union/intersection of two Jordan measurable sets is Jordan measurable using definition

Tags: real-analysis

I know how to use $\partial(A \cup B) \subseteq \partial(A) \cup \partial(B)$ to prove the property for union but is it possible to prove the statement using the definition only?

Comment: What is your definition of Jordan measurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Jordan measurable if the inner and outer Jordan measures are equal, that is

$$m_*(A) :=\sup_{E \subset A} |E| = \inf_{E \supset A} |E| =: m^*(A) ,$$

where $E$ denotes an elementary set (finite union of non-overlapping rectangles) and $|E|$ is the volume of $E$. In this case we denote the Jordan measure  by $m(A) = m^*(A) = m_*(A)$. We have $m^*(A) > m_*(A)$ always if $A$ is not Jordan measurable.

It is easily shown that the Jordan measure of an elementary set is the volume (sum of volumes of composing rectangles), finite unions and intersections of elementary sets are elementary, and for elementary sets $E,F$ we have $|E\cup F|+ |E\cap F| = |E| + |F|$.

To prove that $A,B$ Jordan measureable implies that $A \cup B$ and $A\cap B$ are Jordan measurable, first consider that $A,B$ are bounded.

If $E,F$ are elementary sets such that $E \supset A$  and $F \supset B$, then

$$m^*(A\cup B) + m^*(A\cap B) \leqslant |E\cup F| + |E\cap F| = |E| + |F|$$

Taking the infimum over all $E\supset A$ and $F\supset B$ it follows that

$$\tag{1}m^*(A\cup B) + m^*(A\cap B) \leqslant m^*(A) + m^*(B) = m(A) + m(B)$$

Similarly with elementary sets $E\subset A$ and $F \subset B$ it follows that

$$\tag{2}m_*(A\cup B) + m_*(A\cap B) \geqslant m_*(A) + m_*(B)= m(A) + m(B)$$

Subtracting (2) from (1) we get

$$m^*(A\cup B) - m_*(A\cup B) + m^*(A\cap B)-m_*(A\cap B) \leqslant 0$$

Since, seperately, $m^*(A\cup B) - m_*(A\cup B) \geqslant 0$ and $m^*(A\cap B)-m_*(A\cap B) \geqslant 0$ and the sum of those differences is no bigger than $0$ we must have

$$ m^*(A\cup B) = m_*(A\cup B), \quad m^*(A\cap B)=m_*(A\cap B), $$
and so the union and intersection are Jordan measurable.

Extension of the proof when at least one of $A$ and $B$ are unbounded is straightforward if that situation is allowed under your definition of Jordan measurability.

Comment: my jordan definition is that the function XE is riemann integrable but i do not actually understand what function XE is really

Comment: and thank you for the explanation, is your definition related to mine?

Comment: intuitively its the same since lower and upper bound collide to be riemann integrable but i am not sure to make the connection since E is a set not a function range

Comment: also im confused to how you can take sup of E and F to derive (1) why is E and F bounded?

Comment: I’m using this definition of [Jordan measure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure). There are equivalent definitions. I assume you are thinking about one based on the integral of the characteristic function. Also I am not taking the sup and inf of $E$.  The inner measure is the sup of $|E|$ where $|\cdot|$ means volume — i.e., the sup of the volume of all elementary sets contained in $A$.

Comment: got it, im still confused about what the inner meausre it, can you explain "Taking the supremum over all ⊃ and ⊃ it follows that..." like what makes E bounded and smaller than m*(A)? I thought ⊃ so E is bigger than A

Comment: Sorry — no wonder you were confused. That is a typo which I just corrected. I meant taking the “infimum” -  not the “supremum”. $m^*A = \inf_{E\supset A} |E|$

Comment: i did think that but even that i am confused sorry; if we take inf then how do we gaurantee ∗()+∗() is great or equal to ∗(∪)+∗(∩) since we do not know that ||+||<inf but we do know ||+||<sup

Comment: or you were not trying to use transitional property of inequality to derive (1)? maybe i misunderstood your logic

Comment: To save writing let $LHS = m^*(A\cup B) + m^*(A\cap B)$. We have $LHS \leqslant |E| + |F|$ for ALL $E \supset A$ and $F \supset B$. Hence, with $F$ fixed we have $LHS - |F| \leqslant |E|$ for all $E \supset A$ and as a lower bound $LHS - |F|$ is less than or equal to the greatest lower bound $\inf_{E\supset A} |E| = m^*(A)$. Thus $LHS - |F| \leqslant m^*(A) \implies LHS \leqslant m^*(A) + |F| \implies LHS - m^*(A) \leqslant |F|$ for all $F \supset B$.  Repeat the argument taking the infimum over $|F|$ and you get the result (1).

Comment: i understand now and sincere apologies, sorry ill check this answer

Comment: may i ask one more question i apologize; I am also trying to prove the difference of two jordan sets is still measurable, I have proved that using ∂(E \ F ) ⊂ ∂E ∪ ∂F, but can you give me maybe some hints on how to prove using definition only?

Comment: Yes -- I saw that one.  I will try to help you.  By definition you mean using the inner and outer Jordan measure like what we have done here - correct?

Comment: my definition is "Given a bounded set E being a subset of RN , let R be a rectangle containing E. We say that E is Jordan measurable if the function E is Riemann integrable over R." but like you mentioned, they are the same definition so so I can use your definition, correct? thanks

Comment: So your definition is $A$ is Jordan measurable if the indicator function $\chi_A$ is Riemann integrable.  The definitions are equivalent because $A$ is Jordan measureable (according to equal inner and outer Jordan measure) if and only if the boundary $\partial A$ has content zero. I'll try for a proof using the inner/outer measure definition.  You might want to post questions later that require only the definition based on Riemann integrability be used  -- if that is really important to you.

Comment: that makes more sense now thank you, and i will do that in the future; will you be posting here for your set difference proof or in my other post, thank you